# filter by Sum without Grouping

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i have a resultset that i generate from a query that Looks like this:

```
  Select Employee, Month, (select case when Status = '---' then 0 Else 1 end) as PlaningValue      
  From   PlanningTable PT
  Where  Month >= @From Month and Month <= @ToMonth
```

The Result of this Looks something like this:

```
|Employee|  Month  | PlaningValue |
|George  | 2014-01 |            1 |
|George  | 2014-02 |            1 |
|George  | 2014-03 |            0 |
|Andrew  | 2014-01 |            0 |
|Andrew  | 2014-02 |            1 |
|Andrew  | 2014-03 |            0 |
|Howard  | 2014-01 |            1 |
|Howard  | 2014-02 |            1 |
|Howard  | 2014-03 |            1 |
```

Now what i want is the following:

Filter out Employee's who, over the three month period, have a total planing Value of 3,
in the example above, Howard would be filtered out.

Is there a way to do this nicely or is it all just impossible to even thin ?

**(Remark: Since i am going to use the Query on Reporting Services, i can't use the OVER function)**

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Weird CASE syntax. Why you selecting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be SQL Server syntax, as such I you can use [windowed functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Employee,
            Month,
            PlanningValue = CASE WHEN Status = '---' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
            Total = SUM(CASE WHEN Status = '---' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY Employee)
    FROM    PlanningTable
    WHERE   Month >= @FromDate
    AND     Month <= @ToMonth
)
SELECT  Employee, Month, PlanningValue
FROM    CTE
WHERE   Total != 3;
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd13d/6)**

Comment: I think the OP wants `WHERE Total <> 3`

Comment: Thanks for the Answer,
the issue i am having now is that i am not able to Unionize the Results with another query, i have added a semicolon to make the above answer work before WITH,
but i can't UNION the results with another query i have, is there something i can do ?

Comment: and i have just realised that i can't use windowed functions in Reporting Services
It says the OVER function is not supported

Comment: SSRS does support the use of OVER, although the comment beneath [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9034758/1048425) would indicate SSRS query studio can cause errors with it. There is no reason you shouldn't be able to use UNION with a CTE, the CTE just has to come first, but if it is a problem just move it to a subquery - [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd13d/8)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select pt.employee, pt.month, pt.planningvalue
from planningtable pt
   join planningtable pt2 on pt.employee = pt2.employee
   join planningtable pt3 on pt.employee = pt3.employee
   join planningtable pt4 on pt.employee = pt4.employee
where month >= @mofrom and month <= @tomonth
   and pt2.month = @tomonth
   and pt3.month in (select month from planningtable where month > @mofrom and month < @tomonth)
   and pt4.month = @mofrom
   and pt2.planningvalue + pt3.planningvalue + pt4.planningvalue <> 3
```