# Alternative to over(partition...) function, because it is not supported

Tags: partition

The solution to this question might be simple, but I can't translate other posts about this topic into my own script.

I'm looking for a query to select the highest delivery time for each consignment number, since a consignment can have more than one delivery time's, because it can have more than one parcels.

I came up with this query, and it works fine when I'm using SQL server.

```
select 
    DELIVERYTIME 
from (
    select 
        h_parcel.CONSIGNMENT, S_PARCEL.DELIVERYTIME,
        (row_number() over(partition by h_parcel.CONSIGNMENT order by S_PARCEL.DELIVERYTIME desc)) as rn
    from 
        S_PARCEL 
    inner join 
        h_parcel on h_parcel.h_parcel = s_parcel.h_parcel) as t
where 
    t.rn = 1
```

This code is used to fill a column in an ETL process, which is done in Visual Studio. Visual Studio does not support the function `over(partition by....)`, so this code has to be translated into a code without the partition function. Can someone please help me :)?

Thanks.

Comment: "Visual Studio" is an IDE, it doesn't understand *any* SQL directly. Specify the exact component / library / context / datasource / thing - which is *not* "VS" - that "does not support this function". Including the actual error message(s), if any, may also be useful.

Comment: An integration services project from the Business Intelligence pack is used in VS. The actual error is the following: "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.". Pretty useless one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028966/substitute-command-for-over-in-ssrs , https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b7fe6f4-abf9-46ce-be5c-d655f1f87fbb/the-over-sql-construct-or-statement-is-not-supported - seems to be a designer issue, possibly built in the era of a superseded SQL Server version. Considering editing the tags and specifying the version of the tool(s) used.

Comment: Well, I'm just looking for an alternative code with basic used functions to give the same results